# Windows Notifications, "Set up a back up" keeps poping up

Tags: windows-7, backup, notifications, windows-backup

I have Windows 7 and keep getting this Windows Notification, "Set up a back up".  This message keeps popping up, even though I have it checked off to never show these messages.   This is quite annoying.  Does anyone know why Windows is ignoring my preference and keeps showing this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use the Action Center to disable messages about backup?
http://blogs.howtogeek.com/mysticgeek/2009/04/21/how-to-manage-action-center-in-windows-7/

.
Hit "Change Action Center Settings" on the left

.
[image]

Un-tick "Windows Backup", hit OK
.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To hide the messages from Windows Backup, do this:

```
Go to the Action Center -> In the Maintenance list, select "Turn off 
messages about Windows Backup"
```

To hide all notifications from the Action Center, do the following:

```
Click the upward arrow, left of the notification area -> Customize -> 
Set the combobox for "Action Center" to "Hide icons and notifications"
```